# Invoking the MediaWiki Page Parser to get HTML?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'd like to get the HTML for a MediaWiki Page, that is I want to run the MediaWiki Markup through the parser. Now, I know I could just use some external Parser, but most of them do not support Transclusion and (naturally) Extensions, so my output will be different.

As I have access to the MediaWiki installation, I wonder if I can just use the built-in parser to render me the page. I don't want to do screen scraping because of all the other stuff on the page (navigation, sidebar, javascript and css includes etc.), I literally just want the body.

If it matters, it is running MediaWiki 1.12 on PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use action=render; eg index.php?title=Article_title&action=render

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that, as a matter of fact, I remember doing this very thing in many of my extensions available [here](http://code.google.com/p/mediawiki/).

Found one of my extension that does this: [SecureTransclusion](http://mediawiki.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/SecureTransclusion/).

snippet follows:

```
public function mg_strans( &$parser, $page, $errorMessage = null, $timeout = 5 ) {

    if (!self::checkExecuteRight( $parser->mTitle ))
        return 'SecureTransclusion: '.wfMsg('badaccess');

    $title = Title::newFromText( $page );
    if (!is_object( $title ))
        return 'SecureTransclusion: '.wfMsg('badtitle')." ($page)";

    if ( $title->isTrans() )
        $content = $this->getRemotePage( $parser, $title, $errorMessage, $timeout );
    else
        $content = $this->getLocalPage( $title, $errorMessage );

    $po = $parser->parse( $content, $parser->mTitle, new ParserOptions() );
    $html = $po->getText();

    return array( $html, 'noparse' => true, 'isHTML' => true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should help! I assume that $page is the title of the Page and not the WikiText?

Answer (score 2):

How about using the current MediaWiki parser?  Just grab the converted output, say

from `<!-- start content -->` to either `<div class="printfooter">`

or `NewPP limit report`.  The latter begins the preprocessor's statistics.  That way all the side frames and banners are omitted.

Comment: That requires the design to be constant, so every design change may break the parser by removing the strings the parser looks for.

Comment: True enough, but it's up to the implementer to decide if that's an acceptable tradeoff. I just think of the ideas; it's up to others to decide whether to use them—or modify further as suitable for the problem.